# Can bind be used to forward a variadic number of arguments?

Tags: c++, c++14, perfect-forwarding, stdbind

In C++14, I can write a lambda that does perfect forwarding on an arbitrary number of arguments:

```
template<typename... Args>
void process(Args&&... args);                       // template to forward to


auto wrapper = [](auto&&... args) 
{ 
  std::cout << "Invoking lambda wrapper\n";
  process(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);   // do the forwarding
};
```

Is there a way to achieve the same effect using `bind`? I know that function objects created by `bind` take an arbitrary number of arguments, and I know that such objects uses perfect forwarding for unbound arguments, but is there a way to tell `bind` to create a function object that uses perfect forwarding on every argument passed to it, even if there was no placeholder for it in the call to `bind`?

Comment: o.O the [c++1y] tag doesn't even provide auto-syntax-highlighting.

Comment: I do not think it is possible in general: [func.bind.bind]/2 requires for `bind(F&& f, BoundArgs&&... bound_args)`: *`INVOKE`* `(fd, w1, w1, ..., wN)` shall be a valid expression for some values *w1, w2, ..., wN*, where `N == sizeof...(bound_args)` (but IIRC there's some exception for bind expressions...)

Comment: Well... there's an exception that allows you to write rather silly stuff like `struct wrapper { template<class... Args> int operator()(Args... args) { process(args...); return 42; } }; namespace std { template<> struct is_bind_expression<wrapper> : true_type {}; } void bar(int) {} int main() { auto b = std::bind(bar, wrapper()); b(1); b(1,2.0); }`

Comment: But in general, the problem is to pass a set of overloaded functions as a parameter to a function. And this only works as a function object with an overloaded `operator()` -- a lambda or a manually written function object. (Ok, for a finite set you can also write silly wrappers passing each overload individually.)

Comment: @dyp: Can you please explain how the arguments passed to `b` get forwarded to the `wrapper` object that's bound to `bar`? I would have expected those arguments to be ignored, because there are no placeholders referring to them.

Comment: It is the exception I was talking about: since `wrapper` is recognized as a bind-expression (because of the trait specialization), a special rule applies for `auto b = bind(bar, wrapper())`: All arguments passed to `b` are forwarded to the bound bind-expression (here: the copy of `wrapper()`), that bound bind-expression is called, and the result is taken as the argument for `bar`. That's a bit weird, since any remaining arguments are forwarded as well to `bar`, so they might get forwarded multiple times.

Comment: [Here's something to play around with](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/045d4446a4db8f7b). It's quite... surprising.. and confusing IMO.

Comment: Overload set macros that resolve to particular specializations of a type with `is_bind_expression` specialized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not currently possible, but see http://cplusplus.github.io/EWG/ewg-complete.html#44 for a suggestion to support it:

> As more variadic functions work their way into my C++ code, I'm getting increasingly annoyed that there isn't a variadic bind. There is a tiny bit of annoyance on exactly what to use. There seems to me to be 2 sensible choices (other people may have others)
>
> 1) _args : Use all otherwise unnamed arguments.
>    2) _3onwards : All arguments from the 3rd onwards.
>
> I haven't personally found a need for multiple ranges of variadic arguments, or more complicated chopping (such as getting the last few arguments), and I'd want to hopefully keep this simple if possible!